# span and button not vertically aligned in material card

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I am trying to align a button to the right of an angular material card as

```
<mat-card fxFlex="70" fxFlexOffset="15"  class="margin-10">
    <span>Hello</span>
    <div fxFlex></div>
    <button mat-button>Edit</button>
</mat-card>
```

Though it works, it spoils the vertical alignment of the span and the button. How to fix it?

Stackblitz at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-employee-management-firebase-material-flex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `fxLayoutAlign="start center"` attribute to your card, like this -

```
<mat-card fxFlex="70" fxFlexOffset="15" fxLayoutAlign="start center" class="margin-10">
```

OR

Replace your css like this -

```
.margin-10 {
  margin: 10px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
```

For more information you can refer -

- https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxLayoutAlign-API

Comment: I really don't want to inject CSS to fix this. Is there a way to do via material or flex package?

Answer (score 0):

If you add this to your CSS:

```
.mat-card {
    align-items: center;
}
```

It will align the words Hello with the word Edit in that box. Testing using Chrome.

Comment: I really don't want to inject CSS to fix this. Is there a way to do via material or flex package?

Comment: You could use `fxLayoutAlign="start center"`